# how to separate this into 3 methods.. the thisYear, thisMonth, and pastYear?

Tags: arrays, swift, function, methods, swift3

I want to create a method that separates the thisYear, pastYear and thisMonth..
how to create a method to separate. thank you.

```
func viewWillAppear(view: UIViewController) {
    
        totalRevenueThisCycleWorker.fetchAllRevenueList { (result) in
        
            switch result {
            case .success(let listRevenues):
                //thisYear
               let revenues = listRevenues.filter({ (domain) -> Bool in
                return domain.year == Date().year })
               
               var thisYearRevenueList: [Double] = []
               
               for totalThisYear in revenues {
                thisYearRevenueList.append(totalThisYear.revenue)
               }
               
               let totalRevenuesThisYear = thisYearRevenueList.reduce(0, +)
               let doubleRevenuesThisYear = Double(String(format: "%.2f", totalRevenuesThisYear))
               print("Total Revenues of Current Year  \(doubleRevenuesThisYear ?? 0) ")
               
                
                //thisMonth
                let months: [String] = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
                var highestValue = listRevenues.max { x, y in x.month > y.month }
              
                let month = months[highestValue!.month + 1]
                print("COUNTED  \(month) ")
                
                let monthRevenues = listRevenues.filter({ (domain) -> Bool in
                    return domain.month == highestValue?.month })
                
                var monthRevenueList: [Double] = []
                
                for totalMonth in monthRevenues {
                    monthRevenueList.append(Double(totalMonth.revenue))
                }
                
                let totalRevenuesMonth = monthRevenueList.reduce(0 , +)
                let doubleRevenuesMonth = Double(String(format: "%.2f", totalRevenuesMonth))
                print("Total Revenues of Latest Month in Current Year \(doubleRevenuesMonth ?? 0) ")
               
              
               //pastYear
               let pastRevenues = listRevenues.filter({ (domain) -> Bool in
                return domain.year == Date().year - 1 })
               
               var pastYearRevenueList: [Double] = []
               
               for totalPastYear in pastRevenues {
                pastYearRevenueList.append(totalPastYear.revenue)
               }
               
               let totalRevenuesPastYear = pastYearRevenueList.reduce(0, +)
               print("Total Revenues of Past Year  \(totalRevenuesPastYear) ")
               
               let item = TotalRevenueModel(thisYearTotalRevenue: doubleRevenuesThisYear ?? 0, pastYearTotalRevenue: totalRevenuesPastYear, thisMonthTotalRevenue: doubleRevenuesMonth ?? 0, thisYearMonth: month)

               output?.showRevenues(amounting: item)
            case .failure(_): break
                
            }
    }
    
  }
```

I want to create a method that separates the thisYear, pastYear and thisMonth..
how to create a method to separate. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dissolve the code into 3 methods `thisYear(listRevenues:`), `thisMonth(listRevenues)`, `pastYear(listRevenues:)`

```
func thisYear(listRevenues: [Revenue]) {
    let revenues = listRevenues.filter { $0.year == Date().year }
    let thisYearRevenueList = revenues.map{ $0.revenue }
    let totalRevenuesThisYear = thisYearRevenueList.reduce(0, +)
    let doubleRevenuesThisYear = Double(String(format: "%.2f", totalRevenuesThisYear))
    print("Total Revenues of Current Year  \(doubleRevenuesThisYear ?? 0) ")
}

func thisMonth(listRevenues: [Revenue]) {
    let months: [String] = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    if let highestValue = listRevenues.max({ $0.month > $1.month }) {
        let month = months[highestValue.month + 1]
        print("COUNTED  \(month) ")
        let monthRevenues = listRevenues.filter { $0.month == highestValue.month }
        let monthRevenueList: [Double] = monthRevenues.map { Double($0.revenue) }
        let totalRevenuesMonth = monthRevenueList.reduce(0 , +)
        let doubleRevenuesMonth = Double(String(format: "%.2f", totalRevenuesMonth))
        print("Total Revenues of Latest Month in Current Year \(doubleRevenuesMonth ?? 0) ")
    }
}

func pastYear(listRevenues: [Revenue]) {
    let pastRevenues = listRevenues.filter { $0.year == Date().year - 1 }
    var pastYearRevenueList = pastRevenues.map { $0.revenue }
    let totalRevenuesPastYear = pastYearRevenueList.reduce(0, +)
    print("Total Revenues of Past Year  \(totalRevenuesPastYear) ")
    let item = TotalRevenueModel(thisYearTotalRevenue: doubleRevenuesThisYear ?? 0, pastYearTotalRevenue: totalRevenuesPastYear, thisMonthTotalRevenue: doubleRevenuesMonth ?? 0, thisYearMonth: month)
    output?.showRevenues(amounting: item)
}
```

Now call the methods like,

```
switch result {
case .success(let listRevenues):
    self.thisYear(listRevenues: listRevenues) //thisYear
    self.thisMonth(listRevenues: listRevenues) //thisMonth
    self.pastYear(listRevenues: listRevenues) //pastYear
    
case .failure(_): break
}
```

Modify the code with your own data types, i.e. replace `Revenue` with the type of `listRevenues`.

**Note:** Avoid using force-unwrapping (`!`) unnecessarily.